# What UI is used on this pictures? (node based ui)

Tags: eclipse, user-interface, swt

I'm wondering what UI library is used on the images below (it's from CityEngine). Does anyone know other UI libraries with similar capabilities (free floating, connected nodes with arbitrary UI elements)?
I think it might be a part of Eclipse/JFace/SWT toolkit.

[image]

or:

[image]

Comment: Another image: http://content.screencast.com/users/zbychs/folders/Jing/media/dbcb83dc-ea08-41a6-8e1c-741c62775456/UI.jpg

Answer (score 4):

In particular from your second sample it does indeed seem to be Eclipse/JFace/SWT. To be sure about how it gets that particular graph-like look you'd have to see the source, but my guess is it might use GEF: http://eclipse.org/gef

Answer (score 0):

While the surrounding UI is implemented with Eclipse/JFace/SWT, the editor is *not* implemented with SWT or GEF but with a custom non-public library based on OpenGL.

I found a stack trace where you can clearly see that no SWT/GEF/Draw2D code is involved:
http://forums.esri.com/CityEngine/forum-30031.html.txt

The rendering code lives in the package `org.corebounce.lib3d2`.